# What's our elevator pitch?

Tags: discussion

From [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta):

> ### 4. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?
>
> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about.
>
> This helps in visualising what your community is about and what it is going to be. If you have trouble describing your community in one-line, then its a sign that the community needs to take a relook at its scope and purpose.

Comment: Elevator pitches are actually a little outdated currently. But it is sometimes helpful to have something to throw on a logo or something...

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson: do you have a link to a discussion about that?

Comment: [mSE discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201776/could-we-update-the-7-essential-meta-questions-blog-post-or-not-link-it-promi). Knock yourself out with that post :P

Comment: Here is a newer community resource that discusses the [essential questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta)

Comment: Thanks @AsheeshR, I saw that, but hadn't had a chance to post it back here. Since no-one's answered yet anyway, I've updated my question to use the text from that link.